# How to get Texmaker to place all files into a folder upon compile

Tags: compiling, folders

Mac user here. I'm getting too many files whenever I compile a latex document, and so often each time a make a new file I have to make a folder with the same name to put all of the .pdf, .tex, .aux, etc files in just to clear up the finder.

I would prefer it if there were a setting in Texmaker that would automatically place all of the files into a folder with the document name, so that I don't always have to manually do so. Does anyone know of such a setting or other option?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't want to stop it putting the files there, I know what they're necessary for, I just want everything to be put in a folder so my documents folder doesn't get so congested.

Comment: That answers to that question will still solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally (that's the way it works under Windows), the `Options > Configure` menu,  `TeX commands`tab lets you decide if TeXmaker will put all output files in a `build` subdirectory:

[image]

Comment: When I do this it throws several 'log file not found's at me.

Comment: Is MacTeX configured for search in subdirectories?

Comment: @Bernard I have the same issue. How to configure MacTex to search in subdirectories?