# Pdflatex creates bcf file only when executed from terminal

Tags: biblatex, biber, editors

I had some trouble migrating my latex files from one to another computer: when I compile through my editor (TeXMaker), everything runs fine except when I want to use `biber`/`biblatex`.
Turns out when I execute `pdflatex` through the terminal, it behaves different, runs some package maintenance routines the first time (despite me updating my packages with MiKTex the minute before. I havent seen it doing that again so I guess it does not do maintenance if I use the editor) and actually created the .bcf file biber was missing.

Why is my `pdflatex`, when executed through TeXMaker, behaving so strange, and how can I fix it?

Edit: As moewe mentioned, it was ultimately the build folder. I still dont understand the package maintenance only being done when calling the "wrong" latex file outside of the build folder, but It doesnt matter in the end. Dont use build folders.

Comment: If TeXmaker is configured to move around temporary files, the `.bcf` may not be found. Make sure that you have *unchecked* any option like "use a 'build' subdirectory". Double check that you only have one TeX installation on your system and that both the call from the command line and the TeXmaker call use the same TeX system.

Comment: Unfortunately, we won't be able to say something more useful without more details. Have a look at the `.log` files from the different pdfLaTeX runs: Do they differ? Do they both call the same binary? Can you double-check your compilation settings about the "build" subdirectory?

Comment: Sorry for the late, there is a build directory, which is odd because on earlier TeXmaker installations this never was the default. The log is identical as far as i can see, it calls the same pdftex versions and the same MiKTeX directories. I still cant explain why it only ran package maintenance when i called it from the terminal in the root  folder, not the build folder.

Comment: Make sure that the "build" folder is disabled in the TeXmaker settings (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317638/35864) and try again.